# Compiling latex in VS Code: Recipe terminated with error. Source: LATEX Workshop (Extension)

Tags: vscode, latex-workshop

My VS Code was working properly a couple of weeks ago to compile pdf from latex. Suddenly it stopped compiling my docs. The same happened with TexStudio. I updated my TexLive and texstudio worked again. But I prefer using VS Code because I keep one software for multiple purposes in my PC. Could anyone please help me to figure out what the problem is? (I am Newby) My system is windows.

Here is the output log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/blahblah/Initial Development/LATEX/Idea Development.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22> (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/en/babel-english.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettrine/lettrine.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/minifp/minifp.sty)
Loading lettrine.cfg
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettrine/lettrine.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/yfonts/yfonts.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/authblk.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools/footnote.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfadings.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf-blur/tikzlibraryshadows.blur.code.tex  v1.02, 2012/12/09 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshadows.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/physics/physics.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/hhline.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-pdftex.def))
No file "Idea Development".aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) [1{c:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `aysola2018perceptions' on page 2 undefined on input line 139.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `adjo2021building' on page 2 undefined on input line 139.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `gino2020or' on page 2 undefined on input line 139.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `singh2013managing' on page 2 undefined on input line 139.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ingersoll2022five' on page 2 undefined on input line 139.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `carver2019trouble' on page 2 undefined on input line 139.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ingersoll2021demographic' on page 2 undefined on input line 142.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `goldring2018attrition' on page 2 undefined on input line 142.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `nguyen2021linking' on page 2 undefined on input line 142.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ingersoll2022five' on page 2 undefined on input line 142.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ingersoll2022five' on page 2 undefined on input line 147.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ingersoll2021demographic' on page 2 undefined on input line 147.

[2]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `ingersoll2021demographic' on page 3 undefined on input line 149.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `carver2019trouble' on page 3 undefined on input line 149.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `berg2015oklahoma' on page 3 undefined on input line 149.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `levin2015massachusetts' on page 3 undefined on input line 149.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `swartz2019science' on page 3 undefined on input line 149.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `akay2017ethnic' on page 3 undefined on input line 149.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `mcconnell2018multiple' on page 3 undefined on input line 149.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `nguyen2021linking' on page 3 undefined on input line 154.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `data' on page 3 undefined on input line 154.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `partelow2019make' on page 3 undefined on input line 159.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `evans201950' on page 3 undefined on input line 159.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `aragon2018targeted' on page 3 undefined on input line 159.

[3] [4]
c:/Users/blahblah/Initial Development/LATEX/Idea Development.tex:198: Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   /
l.198 ...tching districts, schools, and teachers.}
                                                   uses a stratification met...
c:/Users/blahblah/Initial Development/LATEX/Idea Development.tex:198: Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   /
l.198 ...tching districts, schools, and teachers.}
                                                   uses a stratification met...
c:/Users/blahblah/Initial Development/LATEX/Idea Development.tex:198: Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   /
l.198 ...tching districts, schools, and teachers.}
                                                   uses a stratification met...

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 212--220

[5]
No file "Idea Development".bbl.

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

[6] (./Idea Development.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information){c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc}<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1095.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1200.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1728.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0700.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0800.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1440.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm2074.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfti1095.pfb>
Output written on "Idea Development.pdf" (6 pages, 167643 bytes).SyncTeX written on "Idea Development.synctex.gz"

Transcript written on "Idea Development.log".
```